# Recursive generic structs with different types in Swift 4

Tags: swift, generics

```
struct Lock<Element: Hashable> {

    var element: Element

    init(_ element: Element, _ args:[Lock<Element>]? = nil) {
        self.element = element
    }
}
```

Is it possible to modify this kind of struct to be able call init() with different `Element` types in arguments?

`Lock("element", [Lock("100")])` it's ok

`Lock("element", [Lock(100)])` this causes an error: *Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Lock<_>'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options for doing this.

The simple solution, improving on @Cristik's answer, is to have another initialiser that doesn't expect another generic parameter:

```
struct Lock<Element> {
    var element: Element

    init(_ element: Element) {
        self.element = element
    }
    init<T>(_ element: Element, _ args: [Lock<T>]?) {
        self.init(element)
    }
}
```

You can then have the code you want above, but you lose the information that `Element` conforms to `Hashable`.

---

Your second option is to create a `protocol` using an `associatedtype`. Using a similar trick with having 2 `init`s, you can do the same except explicitly defining the types:

```
protocol Lock {
    associatedtype Element

    init(_ element: Element)
    init<T>(_ element: Element, _ args: [T]?) where T: Lock
}

struct HashableLock<H: Hashable>: Lock {
    typealias Element = H

    var element: Element

    init(_ element: Element) {
        self.element = element
    }
    init<T>(_ element: Element, _ args: [T]?) where T: Lock {
        self.init(element)
    }
}

struct IntLock: Lock {
    typealias Element = Int

    var element: Int

    init(_ element: Int) {
        self.element = element
    }
    init<T>(_ element: Int, _ args: [T]?) where T: Lock {
        self.init(element)
    }
}
```

Then you can create locks like this:

```
let stringStringLock = HashableLock("element", [HashableLock("100")])
let stringIntLock = HashableLock("element", [IntLock(100)])
```

---

The first version is a lot cleaner but it's more limiting. It's up to you which one to use, depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done.

The reason is that `Element` gets assigned to the type used for the element parameter in `init`. Now that same type has to be used whenever `Element` appears in the struct but if you want the generic type of `Lock` to be anything else, you'll need to declare another generic type.

The problem here is that by adding another generic type to `Lock` (i.e. `Lock<Element, AnotherElement>`) is that now the `Lock` in your `init` will need to specify two generic types, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You might get better results by making the initializer generic:

```
struct Lock<Element: Hashable> {

    var element: Element

    init<T>(_ element: Element, _ args:[Lock<T>]? = nil) {
        self.element = element
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for his example, `Lock("element", [Lock(100)])`

Comment: I think I forgot that it was based on yours, so I've updated my answer to "play nicely" :) And when I said it does work I was referring to my answer. Your answer still doesn't work :p